# coverflow like the picture given

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I want to make `UIScrollView` or cover flow like this i tried some coverflow like icaraousal and etc but those not generate the feel like this one so if anyone knows about this type of cover then please suggest me .

and iCarousal create this type of view see the difference of position and angles of side images

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: @Rajneesh071 i used iCarousel but it not generate the view as above

Comment: you have to implement it....you will not get the exact you want

Comment: but what you want exact?

Comment: @Rajneesh071 check the difference i upload another pic from iCar

Comment: you have to implement sample code according to you..

Comment: @Rajneesh071 i tried but didnt get the desired result

Comment: you have to use 2 custom icarousel ... for this

Comment: @Rajneesh071 i dnt understand how to use 2 iCar for that result ????

Comment: Run iOS Demo code from sample and then switch type to custom.. you will understand what i am saying... one icaro from left other from right..and one image view in middle

Comment: wil u plz share that link with me where i can get that example because i dont see any Custom option in my iCar

Comment: Follow Lithu T.V's link...to download.. nicklockwood-iCarousel-9dbb677->Exampl-> IOS Demo.. run this code.. you will get what i am saying

Comment: these are the types there is no custom type ???


iCarouselTypeLinear
iCarouselTypeRotary
iCarouselTypeInvertedRotary
iCarouselTypeCylinder
iCarouselTypeInvertedCylinder
iCarouselTypeWheel
iCarouselTypeInvertedWheel
iCarouselTypeCoverFlow
iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2
iCarouselTypeTimeMachine
iCarouselTypeInvertedTimeMachine

Comment: after this invertTime machine there is an custom...Just press switch type button in toolbar

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for this [awsome library](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) that will do exactly what you ask for

But you have to do some editing inside to achieve the way you want

It has a large collection of delegates that can be used to achieve what you are looking for

```
@protocol iCarouselDataSource <NSObject>

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel;
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view;

@optional

- (NSUInteger)numberOfPlaceholdersInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel;
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel placeholderViewAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view;
- (NSUInteger)numberOfVisibleItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel;

//deprecated, use carousel:viewForItemAtIndex:reusingView: and carousel:placeholderViewAtIndex:reusingView: instead
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index __deprecated;
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel placeholderViewAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index __deprecated;

@end


@protocol iCarouselDelegate <NSObject>
@optional

- (void)carouselWillBeginScrollingAnimation:(iCarousel *)carousel;
- (void)carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation:(iCarousel *)carousel;
- (void)carouselDidScroll:(iCarousel *)carousel;
- (void)carouselCurrentItemIndexUpdated:(iCarousel *)carousel;
- (void)carouselWillBeginDragging:(iCarousel *)carousel;
- (void)carouselDidEndDragging:(iCarousel *)carousel willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
- (void)carouselWillBeginDecelerating:(iCarousel *)carousel;
- (void)carouselDidEndDecelerating:(iCarousel *)carousel;
- (CGFloat)carouselItemWidth:(iCarousel *)carousel;
- (CGFloat)carouselOffsetMultiplier:(iCarousel *)carousel;
- (BOOL)carouselShouldWrap:(iCarousel *)carousel;
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel itemAlphaForOffset:(CGFloat)offset;
- (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel itemTransformForOffset:(CGFloat)offset baseTransform:(CATransform3D)transform;
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForTransformOption:(iCarouselTranformOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value;

//deprecated, use transformForItemAtIndex:withOffset:baseTransform: instead
- (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel transformForItemView:(UIView *)view withOffset:(CGFloat)offset __deprecated;


- (BOOL)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel shouldSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
```

Comment: Here at stackoverflow we appreciate your support for third party libraries. However, unless you include some more information on what this library does (and your involvement in it's development), I will be forced to mark this answer as SPAM. Adding code examples is sufficient enough for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

**First here best** [Source Code](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

It could be that whatever is setting those numbers in there, is not greatly impressed by you setting the `contentOffset` under its hands. So it just goes on setting what it thinks should be the contentOffset for the next instant - without verifying if the contentOffset has changed in the meantime.

I would subclass `UIScrollView` and put the magic in the `setContentOffset` method. In my experience all content-offset changing passes through that method, even the content-offset changing induced by the internal scrolling. Just do [super `setContentOffset`:..] at some point to pass the message on to the real `UIScrollView`.

Maybe if you put your shifting action in there it will work better. You could at least detect the 3000-off setting of `contentOffset`, and fix it before passing the message on. If you would also override the contentOffset method, you could try and see if you can make a virtual infinite content size, and reduce that to real proportions "under the hood".

[This is also helpful for you..!!!](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html)